# How can I see "all" constructors on AppCode by code completion?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, code-completion, appcode

I am new to ios development and studying SwiftUI.

xCode shows more than 5 constructors of Button.
AppCode shows only 2 constructors of Button.

[image: xCode]
xCode (many constructors)

[image: AppCode]
AppCode (only 2 constructors)

[image: developer document. there exists the constructor whose first parameter is String]
developer document. there exists the constructor whose first parameter is String

[image: The result of Jump to Definition on AppCode. there exists the constructor but not showing on code completion]
The result of Jump to Definition on AppCode. there exists the constructor but not showing on code completion

AppCode should more than constructors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I updated XCode 13.X -> 14.1 and restarted AppCode. It is solved. My AppCode now shows all constructors